# Keeping only the Last occurrences of a data in column on a given date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to pandas so bear with me. I have 1 min interval wise data time frame for few years. Each row have a `Long Stop Loss Signal` column . My index for data frame is date time column.

Ignore the other columns ,

[image]

For simplicity let's take only two days data.

```
                    Long Stop Loss Signal
Date 

2008-01-01 09:55        0
2008-01-01 09:56        1
2008-01-01 09:57        0
...............
2008-01-01 03:28        0
2008-01-01 03:29        1
2008-01-01 03:30        1

2008-01-02 09:55        1
2008-01-02 09:56        1
2008-01-02 09:57        1
...............
2008-01-02 03:28        1
2008-01-02 03:29        0
2008-01-02 03:30        0
```

I'm trying to convert this into data frame as below,

```
                    Long Stop Loss Signal
Date 

2008-01-01 09:55        0
2008-01-01 09:56        0
2008-01-01 09:57        0
...............
2008-01-01 03:28        0
2008-01-01 03:29        0
2008-01-01 03:30        1

2008-01-02 09:55        0
2008-01-02 09:56        0
2008-01-02 09:57        0
...............
2008-01-02 03:28        1
2008-01-02 03:29        0
2008-01-02 03:30        0
```

That is I just wanna keep only the Last occurrence of `Long Stop Loss signal` where it have 1 as its value and fill with 0 for remaining occurrences on the same day. That is for any given day `Long Stop Loss signal` will have max only one occurrence of value 1. Tried `drop_duplicate` and `group` but no luck. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: this is a bit confusing for me. The last occurrence of day 1 is 1, and you kept it on that row and filled the rest with 0's, make sense. For the 2nd day, the last occurrence is 0, but you have a 1 on the above row. Can you please explain a bit more what is your goal?

Comment: Edited the question. I want to keep only the last occurrence of the value `1` for the column `Long Stop Loss Signal `. For day 2 last occurrence of `1` happened at `3.28` so i wanna keep that value alone and fill with `0` for remaining value on that day.

Comment: Should the one `2008-01-02 03:30` be set with `1` instead of `2008-01-02 03:28` according to your definition of Last occurrence ?

Comment: No. Last occurrence of value `1` on the day `2008-01-02` happened at `3.28`. So only that row should have `1` as its value in the column `Long Stop Loss Signal` as shown in the expected output.

Comment: try `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Long Stop','Loss signal'],keep='last')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would groupby `Date.floor('D')` and keep last value, then reindex:

```
resul = df.assign(day=df.index.floor('D')).reset_index()
resul = resul[resul['Long Stop Loss Signal'] == 1].groupby('day').last(
  ).set_index('Date')
resul = resul.reindex(index=df.index).fillna(0).astype('int64')
```

It gives as expected

```
                     Long Stop Loss Signal
Date                                      
2008-01-01 09:55:00                      0
2008-01-01 09:56:00                      0
2008-01-01 09:57:00                      0
2008-01-01 03:28:00                      0
2008-01-01 03:29:00                      0
2008-01-01 03:30:00                      1
2008-01-02 09:55:00                      0
2008-01-02 09:56:00                      0
2008-01-02 09:57:00                      0
2008-01-02 03:28:00                      1
2008-01-02 03:29:00                      0
2008-01-02 03:30:00                      0
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and thank u . I really appreciate ur help.

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` using `dt.day` to get daily results, and use `nlargest(1,keep='last')`on our column of interest. It's important that you use `last` because the default is `first` and will return back the index of first occurrence  of 1. You can store your results in a `list`:

```
id_fm = df.groupby([df.Date.dt.day])['Long Stop Loss Signal'].nlargest(1,keep='last').\
             reset_index()[['level_1']].values.flatten().tolist()

>>> print(id_fm)
Out[213]: [5, 9]
```

Thereafter you could use `isin` with `np.where` to assign back in your column.

```
# Assign back to a column
import numpy as np
df['Long Stop Loss Signal'] = np.where(df.index.isin(id_fm),1,0)
```

---

```
df
                  Date  Long Stop Loss Signal
0  2008-01-01 09:55:00                      0
1  2008-01-01 09:56:00                      0
2  2008-01-01 09:57:00                      0
3  2008-01-01 03:28:00                      0
4  2008-01-01 03:29:00                      0
5  2008-01-01 03:30:00                      1
6  2008-01-02 09:55:00                      0
7  2008-01-02 09:56:00                      0
8  2008-01-02 09:57:00                      0
9  2008-01-02 03:28:00                      1
10 2008-01-02 03:29:00                      0
11 2008-01-02 03:30:00                      0
```